# react state not setting for one key in object only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm genuinely not sure how to explain this one.

I have a profile page on my site (`/profile`), which accesses an API (`/api/testAPI/currentuser.php`)

`currentuser.php` returns the following JSON - `{loggedin: true, uid: "3", username: "TechPhil", permissions: "none"}`

In my react component, I fetch this endpoint in the `componentDidMount()` phase, with the following function

```js
fetch("/api/testAPI/currentuser.php")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            apiResponse: res
          })
        })
```

Don't ask me why, but I am able to access the `uid`, `username` and `permissions` keys just fine, using `this.state.apiResponse.key`, but I for some reason cannot access `loggedin` at all?

I have put my full component code below.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class ProfilePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {apiResponse:{}};
      }
    
      getUser(){
        fetch("/api/testAPI/currentuser.php")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            apiResponse: res
          })
        })
          
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.getUser();
      }

      render() {
        if (this.state.apiResponse.loggedin){
          return(
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Your Profile</h2>
                <p>User ID: {this.state.apiResponse.uid}</p>
                <p>Username: {this.state.apiResponse.username}</p>
                <p>Permissions: {this.state.apiResponse.permissions}</p>
                <Link to="/profile/changepw">Change your Password</Link>
            </div>
         ) 
        } else {
          return(<Redirect to="/login"/>)
        }
      }
}

export default ProfilePage
```

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is `this.state.apiResponse.loggedIn` and not the if statement inside of your render method? What happens if you `console.log` that value just before your render method?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in the dev tools to see what the response is? Have you validated that your `fetch` returns a `response.ok` and no other errors are thrown trying to parse the response? Checked the react-dev-tools to see if and what state is updated to? Tried a `console.log(this.state.apiResponse)` at the start of the render function? Are you sure it's `loggedin` and not `loggedIn`, i.e. is it actually camelCased?